# How to find object code of c++ file

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, objdump

I want  check what is object code of .cpp file .For example file is

File is : lib_mylib.cpp

```
int fun() {   return 2;}

int fun1(void) {  return 2;}

int fun2(void) {   return 2;}
```

I want to  check object code for this file lib_mylib.cpp .I want to know which linux command can I use to  get object code of file lib_mylib.cpp. I tried to objdump command but I am not sure which option of command objdump can I use to see actual object code of the file lib_mylib.cpp

Comment: What do you mean _object code_? Do you want do see the emitted assembly code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "objdump -D lib_file"

the left column will be the 'binary object code' and right column - disassembled one.